# How to switch between applications with one button instead of Super-Tab in a fast way?

Tags: gnome, kde, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop-environment, autokey

I have been using Linux on and off for more than a decade.
The one thing that keeps me from completely turning my back on Windows is a Autohotkey-Script I wrote years ago that allows me to quickly switch between applicaton windows with the press of the Pause Button (I suffer from thumb-related RSI). It essentially simulates pressing Alt-Tab once.
If I want to switch to an arbitrary window different than the last one I can still use Alt-Tab, but for switching between the two most recent windows I can just press Pause.
In GNOME I can set Pause to perform the task of switching between applications, but there is a significant delay, it does not just switch to the next window, making it impossible to quickly switch between two application windows.
And I can no longer use Alt-Tab to switch to an arbitrary window.
**Is there a way to replicate the functionality of this Autohotkey-line in Linux, enabling me to switch between application windows without delay and still maintaing the original functionality of Alt-Tab?**

`PAUSE::Send, {ALTDOWN}{TAB}{ALTUP}`

Preferably a robust way, provided by a Desktop Environment (KDE, GNOME)?

I have looked into https://github.com/autokey/autokey, but I don't know if it will be around in a couple years, whereas Autohotkey has been in use for 20 years now and probably will not go away any time soon.

Any suggestions are more than welcome. Thank you very much :).

Comment: Something existing for 20 years is no guarantee it will continue to exist next year, or tomorrow even.  Similarly just because something is "new" doesn't mean it won't be here in 20 years.  Ultimately if the tool does what you want now, why not use it now?  Kick the problem down the road to when it **might** at some point stop working.  That's not to say there isn't a native solution, but why write off something else that might help you?

Answer (score 0):

In Gnome, you can open "Settings", then scroll to "Keyboard Shortcuts".

There, you can rebind most keyboard shortcuts.  The one you are interested in is called "Switch Applications" and is originally bound to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[image]

---

That said, I rarely use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> anymore.  As a jump to a browser to look for documentation, or a file manager, I find that my last window is rarely the one I want to target.  Instead I use workspaces.

I tend to use one window per workspace.  In Gnome I switch between then with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>, or you can number them and set keybindings to go to specific workspaces. These keybindings can all be rebound.

With other DEs this can be even easier.  I use `i3` a lot for this reason.  I <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to move a window to workspace 8.  Then <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to go there.  Switching between workspaces 7 and 8 works fine, then if I need to get distracted by emails or documentation, I can do that on another workspace without contaminating the flow.  If you like multiple windows per workspace, <kbd>Mod</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> will take you where you want to go.  `i3` can also have its keybindings rebound.

Comment: Thanks for the i3-reccommendation. I'll check that out.
I already tried the change you outlined in your screenshot. However, when I use that key to switch between applications, there is always this slight delay. The list of all open windows pops up for maybe half a second.